# An efficient solution to find if n vertex disjoint path exist

Tags: algorithm, performance, graph-theory

You have been given an r x c grid. The vertices in i row and j column is denoted by (i,j). All vertices in grid have exactly four neighbors except boundary ones which are denoted by (i,j) if i = 1, i = r , j = 1 or j = c. You are given n starting points. Determine whether there are n vertex disjoint paths from starting points to n boundary points.

#### My Solution

This can be modeled as a max-flow problem. The starting points will be sources, boundary targets and each edge and vertex will have capacity of 1. This can be further reduced to generic max flow problem by making each vertex split in two, with capacity of 1 in edge between them, and having a supersource and a supersink connected with sources and targets be edge of capacity one respectively.

After this I can simply check whether there exists a flow in each edge (s , s<sub>i</sub>) where s is supersource and s<sub>i</sub> is i<sup>th</sup> source in i = 1 to n. If it does then the method returns `True` otherwise `False`.

#### Problem

But it seems like using max-flow in this is kind of overkill. It would take some time in preprocessing the graph and the max-flow takes about O(V(E<sup>1/2</sup>)).

So I was wondering if there exists an more efficient solution to compute it?